# A curve over a finite field with apparently no points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I am probably making a really silly mistake but I can't figure it out:

Let $\mathbb F_q$ be a finite field and $a$ an element in it that is not a square. Let $E$ be the elliptic curve corresponding to the equation $y^2 = x^3 + 1$ and $E'$ it's twist $ay^2 = x^3 + 1$. Let $f,g: E, E' \to \mathbb P^1$ be the projection to the $x$ co-ordinate and let $C = E\times_{\mathbb P^1} E'$.

Now, $C$ is a possibly singular curve and let $\pi: \tilde C \to C$ be it's normalization. This is a birational map away from finitely many points and therefore $|\tilde C(\mathbb F_{q^r})| - |C(\mathbb F_{q^r})|$ is bounded independent of $r$. By the Weil bound, $|\tilde C(\mathbb F_{q^r})|$ (and hence $|C(\mathbb F_{q^r})|$) goes to infinity as $r \to \infty$.

On the other hand, a $\mathbb F_{q^r}$ point (with $r$ odd) of $C$ corresponds to a point each on $E,E'$ such that their $x$ co ordinates are equal. But if we fix a value for $x$, then $x^3+ 1$ is either a square in $\mathbb F_{q^r} $ or it isn't and this determines whether there is a corresponding point on $E$ or on $E'$ since r is odd and so the twists continue to be non isomorphic.

In particular, there are no pairs of points on $E,E'$ with the same $x$ co ordinate (apart from finitely many points at infinity independent of $r$) and therefore only finitely many $\mathbb F_{q^r}$ points on $C$, independent of $r$.

I have reached a contradiction so what mistaken assumption did I make?

Comment: A non-square can become a square after a (say, degree 2) field extension.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I restrict to odd r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point may be that in the Weil bound we require $\tilde{C}$ to be absolutely irreducible (or geometrically irreducible)? If we don't, we could have examples like $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_{q^{2}}}^{1}$ which is smooth projective over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ but has an $\mathbb{F}_{q^{r}}$-point (if and) only if $r$ is even. In your case, an affine chart of $C$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{F}_{q}[x,y_{1},y_{2}]/(y_{1}^{2}=x^{3}+1 , ay_{2}^{2}=x^{3}+1)$ which is not geometrically irreducible because of the relation $y_{1}^{2} = ay_{2}^{2}$; thus the normalization $\tilde{C}$ is not geometrically irreducible either.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I came upon the same example. The problem is that the entire curve is defined over the base field but none of the components are so the Weil bound doesn't apply for the individual curves. In my case, base changing to the even extensions, the curve has around 4q points so there are 4 components that come in Galois pairs. Tricky!

Comment: Im not sure about the number of irreducible components any more. It is either 4 or 2...

Comment: I guess from the explicit equations, we see 2 components.

Comment: I think I agree, there should be 2 components $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}[x,y_{1},y_{2}]/(y_{1} = \pm\sqrt{a}y_{2} , y_{1}^{2} = x^{3}+1)$, both isomorphic to $E_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}} \simeq E'_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}}$ (we should assume $\operatorname{char} \mathbb{F}_{q} \ne 2$ here and above).

Comment: Yes, and you only need to pass to the degree two field extension to see this. Fun example :)